# CMake does not find MPI headers for C++

Tags: c++, cmake, mpi

I have read a good deal of the CMake documentation and tried to follow some tutorials but I am still struggling with how to get it to compile a C++ program that links to a library which in turn requires MPI.  My source tree looks like this:

```
scratch:
    CMakelists.txt
    build/
    src/
        mystest.h
        mytest.cc
        mylib/
            CMakeLists.txt
            utils.h
            utils.cc
```

Here are the individual files:

scratch/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Set the project name and version
project (mytest VERSION 1.0)

# Specify the C++ standard to use
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set (EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -Wall")

# Add the utility library
add_subdirectory (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mylib)

# look for doxygen capability
find_package (Doxygen)

# look for MPI capability
find_package (MPI REQUIRED)

if (MPI_FOUND)
    set (EXTRA_INCLUDES ${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set (EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS ${EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS} ${MPI_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS})
    set (EXTRA_LIBS "${EXTRA_LIBS} ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES}")
    set (EXTRA_LIBS "${EXTRA_LIBS} ${MPI_CXX_LINK_FLAGS}")
    # How to set MPI_CXX_COMPILER
else (MPI_FOUND)
    message (SEND_ERROR "This application cannot compile without MPI")
endif(MPI_FOUND)

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    configure_file ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Doxyfile.in" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/Doxyfile" @ONLY)
    add_custom_target (doc
        ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/Doxyfile
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
        )
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)

find_library (
    MATH_LIB
    NAMES m libm # what to look for
    HINTS "/usr/lib" # where to look
)

message(STATUS "MATH_LIB: [${MATH_LIB}]")

if (MATH_LIB)
    message ("Found MATH_LIB: [${MATH_LIB}]")
    set (EXTRA_LIBS "${EXTRA_LIBS} ${MATH_LIB}")
else ()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Did not find MATH lib")
endif ()

set (EXTRA_INCLUDES "${EXTRA_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

message ("Top level CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
message ("Extra CXX flags: " ${EXTRA_CXX_FLAGS})
message ("Extra includes: " ${EXTRA_INCLUDES})
message ("Linked libraries are: " ${EXTRA_LIBS})

file (GLOB SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc")

# Add the executable
add_executable (mytest ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories (mytest PUBLIC ${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (mytest mylib ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})

install (TARGETS mytest DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/mytest.h"
    DESTINATION include)
```

scratch/src/mytest.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string.h>
#include "mylib/utils.h"

/**
@brief Write an opening message

This function calls a function from 
the library

@param &msg is the message to print
*/
void writeMessage ( const string &msg )
{
    libWriteAMessage(msg);
    return;
}

using namespace std;
```

scratch/src/mytest.cc:

```
/**
@file
@brief The main program
*/

#include <mpi.h>
#include "mytest.h"

/**
@brief The main block for running mytest
*/
int main (void)
{
    writeMessage("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

scratch/src/mylib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
file (GLOB SOURCES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cc")
file (GLOB INCLUDES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")

message ("Utility library directory, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

add_library (mylib STATIC ${SOURCES})

# Force the hydratica interface from the directory above
# or else this library will fail

target_include_directories (mylib PUBLIC ${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(mylib)

install (TARGETS mylib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
install (FILES ${INCLUDES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

scratch/src/mylib/utils.h:

```
#ifndef UTILS
#define UTILS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

void libWriteAMessage ( const string &msg );

#endif
```

scratch/src/mylib/utils.cc:

```
#include "utils.h"

void libWriteAMessage ( const string &msg )
{
    time_t now;

    // Get the current time
    time(&now);

    cout << msg << endl;
    cout << "The time is "
         << asctime(localtime(&now));

    return;
}
```

When I cd to build and run cmake .., everything seems to be okay.  Here is the output

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Utility library directory, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: 
-- Found Doxygen: /opt/local/bin/doxygen (found version "1.9.1") found components: doxygen dot 
-- Found MPI_C: /usr/local/lib/libmpi.dylib (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI_CXX: /usr/local/lib/libmpi_cxx.dylib (found version "3.1") 
-- Found MPI: TRUE (found version "3.1")  
-- MATH_LIB: [/usr/lib/libm.dylib]
Found MATH_LIB: [/usr/lib/libm.dylib]
Top level CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: 
Extra CXX flags: -O2 -Wall
Extra includes: /usr/local/include /Users/bullard/Software/scratch/src
Linked libraries are:  /usr/local/lib/libmpi_cxx.dylib/usr/local/lib/libmpi.dylib  /usr/lib/libm.dylib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/bullard/Software/scratch/build
```

Cmake evidently found the MPI libraries and include files.  But when I run make, I receive the error:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/mylib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/utils.cc.o
In file included from /Users/bullard/Software/scratch/src/mylib/utils.cc:6:
/Users/bullard/Software/scratch/src/mylib/utils.h:11:10: fatal error: 'mpi.h' file
      not found
#include <mpi.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/mylib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/utils.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/mylib/CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did verify that mpi.h is located in /usr/local/include, which is one of the paths that Cmake found when searching for the MPI package.  So I have a feeling that I am still missing some kind of directive in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file.

I'm sure this is a trivial question, but I am having some trouble understanding the CMake documentation.

Comment: Please, add the **code** into the **question post** itself. It is a requirement of Stack Overflow, and *link* to the code doesn't fulfil that requirement. See [ask],

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code into the question post as requested.

Comment: You are entering into `src/mylib` subdirectory (with `add_subdirectory`) command **before** call to `find_package(MPI)`. That way, variables like `MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS` are not set when `src/mylib/CMakeLists.txt` is parsed, and inside that script `target_include_directories (mylib PUBLIC ${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})` does nothing.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.  I obviously did not realize the importance of the ordering of the commands would be, and your explanation helps clear that up for me.  If you change your comment to an answer I will accept it.